# How to pass an Id to a query that is not being called in the component during refetchQuery in apollo/graphql/react

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to fetch a query that needs an `id` to be passed to it. However I am not calling the query in the component. I tried passing it in the export with `options`, but couldn't get that to work.

Here is what I have:

```
 this.props
  .addLyricToSong({
    variables: {
      content: this.state.content,
      songId: this.props.songId
    },
    refetchQueries: [{query: fetchSong}]
  });
```

The error I get as I said is that the query `fetchSong` needs an `id` to be passed to it.

I tried this at the bottom:

```
options: props => {
  return { variables: { id: props.songId } };
}
```

but as I said I don't call this query in the component and I think that is why it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As outlined in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/mutations.html#graphql-mutation-options-refetchQueries), each object that's part of the array passed to `refetchQueries` should consist of two properties:

> query: Query is a required property that accepts a GraphQL query
>   created with graphql-tag’s gql template string tag. It should contain
>   a single GraphQL query operation that will be executed once the
>   mutation has completed.
>
> [variables]: Is an optional object of
>   variables that is required when query accepts some variables.

So if your `fetchSong` query takes any variables, you'll need to pass in those variables as well:

```
refetchQueries: [{query: fetchSong, variables: { id: 'someID' }}]
```